# Permision control of Notes and Attchments

Tags: permissions, security

How can we control the CREATE/READ/EDIT/DELETE permission of Notes and Attachments via Profile/Permission set?

Is the permission of Notes and Attachments govern by the parent object like Account, Contacts, Opportuniy?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the old Attachment object or the new File (ContentDocument) object?

Comment: Notes and Files. This is applicable for Lightning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the permission of Notes and Attachments govern by the parent object like Account, Contacts, Opportuniy?

Yes.

Please read [Guidelines for Working with Notes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=notes_del.htm&type=5), as there's a lot in there that I'm not going to repeat here.

Some highlights:

- You need read access on a record to create a note.
- To edit a note, you need edit permission on the note.
- To delete a note, you need to own the note.
- You can only grant additional access for people to view, not edit, a note.
- Depending on your system settings, a note you share is shared with all users in your company when it’s posted:

  - To a feed that all users can see
  - To a profile
  - To a record
  - To a public group